# how to view history command for user root

Tags: linux, freebsd

On FreeBSD 8.1
how to view history command for user root. Detail many sesion , because user root use by 3 people system admin.

Thank all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do that. What you do is setup [sudo](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/) and then make your 3 admins log in using normal user accounts and use sudo to run commands as root. Sudo when correctly set up will allow your admins to carry out their duties and will log all relevant information to the system log files for later auditing.

Comment: well you can still see by pressing the up arrow to get previous command.

Comment: @Anarko_Bizounours:  That will only show the last N commands where N is controlled by HISTFILESIZE or HISTSIZE. Also is you put a space before your command it doesn't get stored in the command history.